# C : Warning about visibility of a struct

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang

I have a complex C project. In a file `message.h` I declare this structure

```
struct message  
{
    int err;
    struct header
    {
        char *protocol_version;         
        char *type;                     
        long int sequence_number;       
    } header;                           
    struct body
    {
        int num_tag;                     
        char *tag_labels[LEN];          
        int num_attr_tag[LEN];          
        char *attr_labels[LEN][LEN];    
        char *attr_values[LEN][LEN];    
        char *attr_types[LEN][LEN];     
    } body;                             
};
```

In the file "castfunctions.h", I include the file "message.h" and I declare the function "setClientNat"

```
#include <message.h>
void *setClientNat(struct message *msg);
```

When I compile, I have this warning

```
castfunctions.h:warning: 
  declaration of 'struct message' will not be visible outside of this function [-Wvisibility]
  void *setClientNat(struct message *msg);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What and where is line `castfunctions.h:36`?

Comment: Did you put the `#include` inside the function body by mistake?

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with the structure you show.  Can you construct a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: Did you declare that `struct` inside a function?

Comment: I insert the declaration of setClientNat at line 36. No I don't put the include inside the function body.

Comment: No I declare that struct in the header file 'message.h'. After, I include this file in another header file 'castfunctions.h', where I declare the function 'setClientNat'.

Comment: If you are not deliberately including either header inside a function, my guess is that you are missing a semicolon or `}` somewhere above `#include <message.h>`, but it is impossible to answer accurately with the information available.

Comment: If I declare `typedef struct Message`, I delete this warning. But I cannot do this because this change generate errors related to other file of the project.

Comment: `message.h` is a pretty generic-looking name. Are you sure you're getting the right one? Maybe another one is hiding in `/usr/include`

Comment: Wait, wait, wait. I can't say with 100% certainty for C++, but if you're compiling this as C, could this be because you have `#include <message.h>` and not `#include "message.h"`?

Answer (score 7):

> declaration of 'struct message' will not be visible outside of this
>   function [-Wvisibility]

That warning means that `struct message` was not declared at that point, so it serves as a useless forward declaration.

This means that the code you show is not the complete truth, your files have a lot more in them that what you show - the error is in the code not shown to us.

Here is a few reasons as to why you might get the warning;

- `#include <message.h>` includes an entierly different file than what you think it does, go look for another message.h elsewhere.
- You have include guards in your message.h like so

> ```
> #ifndef MESSAGE_H
> #define MESSAGE_H 
> struct message { 
> ....
> };
> #endif`
> ```

Then you use the headerfiles in a source file like so:

```
   #include <thisnthat.h>
   #include <message.h>
```

And it just so happened that the `<thisnthat.h>` file also defined a
MESSAGE_H macro, rendering the entire message.h invisible.
Alternatively the `thisnthat.h` header have a `#define message something_else`

- There's a syntax error somewhere in the header files directly or indirectly included together with message.h. Go hunt for missing ; or { or }
- You misspelled something. Your comment states the error is gone when you did a `typedef struct Message`  which for some reason have `Message` with a capital `M`. So somewhere you're mixing up `struct Message` vs `struct message`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to nos' answer you should run gcc with the `-E` option instead of `-c`. This will output the preprocessed translation unit, so you can see what the compiler really sees. The output also mentions each file that gets included.