# Warning: declaration of '...' will not be visible outside this function [-Wvisibility]

Tags: c

First of all, I've googled the error and read these answers:

- [I don't understand why compiler is giving me error with this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603182/i-dont-understand-why-compiler-is-giving-me-error-with-this-code)
- [C : Warning about visibility of a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007364/c-warning-about-visibility-of-a-struct)

But none of them helped me, so here we are.

The problem resides somewhere in between these 2 structures, `prx_data_s` which store generic data and `prx_ops_s` that defines pointers to functions that will use that data.

I'll simplify the sources for the example:

**prx_data.h**

```
#ifndef PRX_EXAMPLE_DATA_H
#define PRX_EXAMPLE_DATA_H

#include "prx_ops.h"

struct prx_data_s {
    enum  prx_op_t op;
    char *keyquery;
};

char *get_query(struct prx_data_s *dt);

#endif
```

**prx_data.c**

```
#include "prx_data.h"

char *get_query(struct prx_data_s *dt)
{
    return dt->keyquery;
}
```

**prx_ops.h**

```
#ifndef PRX_EXAMPLE_OPS_H
#define PRX_EXAMPLE_OPS_H

#include "prx_data.h"

enum prx_op_t {
    PRX_EXAMPLE_OP = 2
};

struct prx_ops_s {
    int (*dec) (struct prx_data_s *);
};

#endif
```

I'm trying to compile the object from the above example with:

```
clang -c prx_data.c -o prx_data.o -std=c11 -g -Wall
```

And this is the output error:

```
In file included from prx_data.c:1:
In file included from ./prx_data.h:4:
./prx_ops.h:11:24: warning: declaration of 'struct prx_data_s' will not be visible outside of this function [-Wvisibility]
int (*dec) (struct prx_data_s *);
                   ^
```

All help is welcome, thanks :)

Comment: You have a circular include graph - prx_ops includes prx_data and vice versa. Although the include guards break any infinite loop, in your example the ops header gets read first, resulting in a forward declaration of the struct.

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew circular dependencies were a thing, it makes sense. Thanks @TypeIA!

Comment: in general, as you found out, you should not define functions within a header file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a problem with circular dependencies in your header:

```
prx_data.h:

#include "prx_ops.h" <<< Here we do not yet see the struct definition

    prx_ops.h:

    #include "prx_data.h"  <<<< Nothing will be included due to inclusion guards.

    struct prx_ops_s {
       int (*dec) (struct prx_data_s *);  <<<< Here a new struct type is declared.
    };

later back in prx_data.h:

struct prx_data_s {
  enum  prx_op_t op;
  char *keyquery;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

When reading `prx_ops.h`, you dont 't have `prx_data.h` included because the compiler is reading `prx_ops.h` from the include at the beginning of `prx_data.h`. You thus have to forward declare it.

Try adding

```
struct prx_data_s;
```

at the beginning of prx_ops.h`

Hope that helps ~~